# display 2D array in matrix format

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my **2D array** to be displayed as **matrix** format. For that which layout is suitable? Can I have any example for that?

Comment: After looking at the android layouts available which one do you think is appropriate?

Comment: I think table layout. bt i ws nt so sure that's y i have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a `TableLayout` with `TextView`s inside.

But if you want to display a large array, you should make the matrix scrollable in both directions. Below is the code that populates a matrix that is displayed as a series of `EditText`s inside rows, inside a `TableLayout`. The `TableLayout` is made scrollable in both directions using two ScrollView. Adapt the code to your needs. `table` is the `TableLayout` with the id `tableLayout1`.

```
private void fillTable(final int n, final double[][] matrix, TableLayout table) {
table.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        EditText edit = new EditText(OutputActivity.this);
        edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        edit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        edit.setText(Double.toString(matrix[i][j]));

        edit.setKeyListener(null);
        row.addView(edit);
    }
    table.addView(row);
}
}
```

The layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```